# Regex: match consecutive punctuation marks and replace by the first

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to remove some predefined consecutive punctuation marks and replace them with the first. Thus:

1. u.s., -> u.s.
2. u.s. -> u.s.
3. u.s.! -> u.s.
4. hiiii!!!, -> hiiii!

I tried the following code:

```
import re
r = re.compile(r'([.,/#!$%^&*;:{}=-_`~()])*\1')
n = r.sub(r'\1', "ews by almalki : Tornado, flood deaths reach 18 in U.s., more storms ahead ")
print(n)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to capture the first punctuation mark and match the rest:

```
([.,/#!$%^&*;:{}=_`~()-])[.,/#!$%^&*;:{}=_`~()-]+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jxEADZ/1)

Note that the `-` must be put at the end (or start) of the character class in order not to create a range (or it can be escaped inside the character class).

**Details**:

- `` ([.,/#!$%^&*;:{}=_`~()-]) `` - capturing group with the punctuation symbols you defined
- `` [.,/#!$%^&*;:{}=_`~()-]+ `` - 1+ punctuation symbols

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/Uv4zeM):

```
import re
r = re.compile(r'([.,/#!$%^&*;:{}=_`~()-])[.,/#!$%^&*;:{}=_`~()-]+')
n = r.sub(r'\1', "ews by almalki : Tornado, flood deaths reach 18 in U.s., more storms ahead ")
print(n)
```

Comment: Ok `@` was not included.

Comment: @MYGz Well, that is why I used the "punctuation symbols you defined" wording. `string.punctuation` yields `!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_\`{|}~` symbols, and the character class would look like `[\\!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^_\`{|}~-]` then ([regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nrrOOZ/1)).